# Form rendering with choice fields terrible performance

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a variety of choice fields in a form I'm creating, but all of them are loaded from PHP arrays that are defined in code. `createForm()` is given an empty model. Each field, when rendered with `form_row()` in twig tacks on about 2 seconds to render, each, making the request take about 8 or 9 seconds, which is ridiculous. I've tried searching, reading, etc. and from what I can tell I am following best practices. There are no database queries being run. Please help me nail down this huge performance problem.

Let's start with the form type:

```
class SubscriptionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('latitude', 'hidden')
            ->add('longitude', 'hidden')
            ->add('crop', 'choice', [
                'choices' => Crop::getFormChoices(),
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('infliction', 'choice', [
                'choices' => Infliction::getFormChoices(),
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('emergenceDate', 'date')
            ->add('threshold', 'choice', [
                'choices' => Threshold::getFormChoices(),
                'label' => 'Severity threshold',
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => 'Subscribe']);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'PlantPath\Bundle\VDIFNBundle\Entity\Subscription',
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'subscription';
    }
}
```

Then, in my controller:

```
public function formAction(Request $request)
{
    $subscription = new Subscription();

    $form = $this->createForm(new SubscriptionType(), $subscription);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // ...
    }

    return $this->render('PlantPathVDIFNBundle:Subscription:form.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Subscription/form.html.twig:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'subscription-form'}}) }}
{{ form_row(form.crop) }}
{{ form_row(form.infliction) }}
{{ form_row(form.emergenceDate) }}
{{ form_row(form.threshold) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

As I mentioned, each call to `form_row()` takes a good two seconds. If I take out all the `form_row()`s and the `form_end()`, the template is rendered (without a form) in milliseconds. I cannot fathom why Symfony needs over 8 seconds to render several lines of HTML for a blank form.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine, so the only solution you have is to do some profiling to find what takes time. You can use xdebug or something else.

Comment: Thanks, this was much more helpful than the Symfony profiler. It turns out while rendering the template it was pushing about 100 `warning` events saying "Translation not found." to Monolog, and I had a custom log handler for sentry, which was making a synchronous HTTP request for each one.

Now I'm looking into what exactly is pushing this warning, because there is no additional information with it.

Answer (score 0):

The blocks for rendering the choice fields in bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig contains '|trans' filter which tries to find translation for each option.
Override choice_widget_options block in your twig file, if you do not wish to translate. This should eliminate the warning messages caused due to translation.